# How to type mapDispatchToProps in a component props interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a connected component with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` and a `connect` HOC from `react-redux`, and I want to create type definitions for the component as briefly and as future proof as it is possible.

For `mapStateToProps` I can use `ReturnType` and it works fine:

```
interface Props extends ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> {};

class ConnectedComponent extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    // `variableFromState` gets inferred here
    console.log(this.props.variableFromState);

    return (
      // ...
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
  variableFromState: state.variable,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedComponent);
```

However for `mapDispatchToProps` I use a simple object, and I am not sure how to achieve the save effect with this, as I did for `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
  // ...
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  action1,
  action2,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedComponent);
```

I am aware that I could use `bindActionsCreators` and then I could use the `ReturnType`, but I want to use a simple object here.

What I tried is to add the `typeof <action>` in the props interface, but it is still tedious to write for every component and every action.

```
interface Props extends ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> {
  action1: typeof action1;
  action2: typeof action2;
};
```

Also it is wrong when I use async thunk actions, because it infers the following for the action return value in the component, and not the value it really returns.

```
(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, null, AnyAction> & ThunkDispatch<any, undefined, AnyAction> & Dispatch<AnyAction>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, how to achieve the effect I wanted with as less explicit typing as it is possible:

```
interface Props extends ConnectedProps<typeof connector> {};

class ConnectedComponent extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    // Here actions, and state is inferred correctly with this method
    return (
      // ...
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
  variableFromState: state.variable,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  action1,
  action2,
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default connector(ConnectedComponent);
```